# custom Conversation dialog new intents

Tags: watson-virtual-agent

In trying to work with custom dialog I have encountered some issues. While using Virtual Agent as a testing grounds, I have been trying to redirect all input to a Conversation workspace by doing the following:

1. Disabling all intents other than the 3 mandated ones (Connect to Agent, Agent Settings, None of the Above).
2. Configure custom dialog to be invoked on the intent "None of the Above".

This should have the effect of sending all input to the "None of the Above" which essentially sends any input straight into the Conversation workspace. When testing this approach without tying in the workspace, the simple canned message does get invoked on any input as expected. However, when adding the workspace ID and Conversation credentials (checked several times for accuracy), I get the error:

Error -- Unable to create custom dialog service

So I am wondering why this might occur.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but this error means there is a missing or incorrect workspace attribute.
Please use the following values:
Conversation endpoint
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api"
API Version:
"2016-07-11"

Answer (score -1):

CaesarOG:

The Off_Topic intent is "special" - it invokes your custom workspace without forcing the intent to be `Off_Topic` (unlike the other intents in Watson Virtual Agent). This design decision was done so that you could do the sort of thing you are trying to accomplish. If in your custom Conversation workspace you have custom intents, and you add your custom dialog to respond to those intents, the Watson Virtual Agent will have Conversation evaluate your utterances against the custom intent detection system and trigger your custom dialog as you would expect.